# Pushwoosh (cordova) custom iOS push notification long vibration

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, pushwoosh

is it possible to create a push notification from Pushwoosh for cordova that triggers a long vibration on iOS? I could only find "force vibration"...

If not, are there any other API's that allow this?

Thanks